# get the form processing data immediately after form submitting in Javascript, before page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have used Django to develop a web app.
After form submit, I want to get the form processing result( msg here in my case)  immediately in view function, before page refresh.

url.py:

```
path('index/', views.form_process, name='index'),
```

view.py

```
 def form_process(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
                Form_instance = Form(data=request.POST)
                if Form_instance.is_valid():
                        msg="success"
                else:
                        msg="fail"               

                return render(request, 'index.html', context={'msg': msg})
```

index.html

```
<form id="myform">
...

 </form>
  <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="submit">submit</button>

 

<script>
function myFunction() {
...
$("#myform").submit();

    if ('{{msg}}'.includes('success'))
    {alert("success");
     }

}
</script>
```

Now the msg always send to the js after page refresh. My boss want to make it pop up immediately after form submitting,  before page refresh.
How could  get the msg generated in view function immediately after form submitting in Javascript, before page refresh.

I have tried ajax but failed to capture the msg, no alert form ajax popped up:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
        url : '/index/',    //I also tried 127.0.0.1:8000/index, also no pop up
        type: 'get',
        success : function (response) {
            alert("The server says: " + response);
        }
    })
;
```

How could I get the form processing data immediately after form submitting in Javascript, before page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

The type in ajaxForm should be POST not get

Comment: I want to get a result of form processing in ajax , not post the form using ajax

Comment: But your msg = 'success' is under POST not GET, the snippet you shared doesn't have a GET

Comment: POST is for form submitting, after submitting the form, I want to get the form processing result("success" or "fail") in real time in javascript, so not possible POST for get "success" msg in javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "result of  Form Processing", the form needs to be processed to get the result, according to your coded, this shall be done by POST not GET.